# Definition simple modules and submodules

Tags: modules, definition

I'm having some trouble understanding the definition of a simple module  and submodule.
An R-module M is simple if the only submodules are M and 0. A submodule is a subgroup U of M such that r.u is in U for all r in R and u in U.

Now to my question: is Z/2Z simple? or are Z/0Z ≅ Z, Z/1Z ≅ 0 and Z/2Z submodules.

I feel like Z isn't a subgroup of Z/2Z, this is why I thought it should be simple.

Is Z/3Z a non-simple module because Z/2Z is ​​a submodule?

Or do you have better examples from the residual class ring? I would be very grateful to get some  help!

Comment: I think you should try looking up the definition of submodules and try again.

Comment: Well, the only definition I have is the one I have already given.

Comment: Remember that a $\;\Bbb Z\,-$ module is just an abelian group. That could make things easier to grasp. The abelian group $\;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ is **not** a submodule of $\;\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\;$ . In fact, it isn't even a subset...I think you may want to try to understand more thoroughly quotient modules (or quotient groups)>

Comment: @DonAntonio So do you have an example for a submodule of Z/2Z and Z/3Z? I just thought it would be a subset since Z/2Z := {[0],[1]} and Z/3Z:= {[0],[1],[2]}. Where is my misconception?

Comment: Both $\;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\,,\,\,\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\;$ are simple groups. It is not hard, using Lagrange's Theorem for finite group, to prove that the group $\;\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\;$ is simple iff $\;n\;$ is a prime number. Now, $\;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\{[0],[1]\}\;$ , but these elements are like using $\;0,1\;$ modulo $\;2\;$ ...! and likewise with $\;\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z=\{[0],[1],[2]\}\;$ , which are like $\;0,1,2\;$ modulo 3. The operations are very different, and thus$\;[0]\in\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ represents all the even numbers in $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , whereas $\;[0]\in\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\;$ represents all multiple of $\;3\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio well thanks a lot! But Z/2Z would be a submodule of Z/4Z?

Comment: Not again...though $\;Z/4\Bbb Z\;$ has a submodule isomorphic with $\;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$ . The operations in both modules are different and that matters a lot! In the former one we have sum and multiplication modulo $\;4\;$ ,whereas in the former they are modulo $\;2\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh...this topic is quite hard to me, I am sorry. I think it would help me if you could give me an example of a submodule of Z/4Z?

Comment: TIf $\;\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z=\{0,1,2,3\}\mod 4\;$ (to avoid the annoying $\;[0],[1]\;$ and etc.), then $\;M:=\{0,2\}\;$ is a submodule of $\;A:=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\;$ isomorphic with $\;\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;$. In fact, that is the only non-trivial submodule of $\;A\;$ ...I don't know what course are you taking but I'd say that it'd help you if you already had taken a basic course in group theory.